Trying WP editor to load full size image (not '300x300')
The site used to have a plugin that created a lot of image sizes from uploads (150, 300, 800 px etc). I removed these images from the uploads folder bc they were not used by the theme.
Now, the WP Editor and Media Library show broken images for thumbnails and previews because it's trying to load the imagename-150x150.jpg version.
The site itself works fine, how to get the images to show in WordPress UI itself?
Inspect view shows the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

